# How to reference a element within a table

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am need of help. I am trying to figure out the below:

```
<script>
var ct = 1;
function new_bank()
{
ct++;
var div1 = document.createElement('div');
div1.id = ct;
// bank to delete extended form elements
var delLink = '<a href="javascript:delIt('+ ct +')">delete</a>';

div1.innerHTML = 
document.getElementById("newbanktpl").innerHTML + delLink;
document.getElementById('newbank').appendChild(div1);
}
// function to delete the newly added set of elements
function delIt(eleId)
{
d = document;
var ele = d.getElementById(eleId);
var parentEle = d.getElementById('newbank');
parentEle.removeChild(ele);
findTotalA();
}
</script>


<!-- Template -->
<div id="newbanktpl">
<table>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td><textarea name="BankAccount[]"></textarea></td>
  <td><input type="number" onblur="findTotalA()" name="Value[]"/></td>
  <td><input type="number" name="Ownership[]" /></td>
  <td>**ADD DELETED LINK HERE** </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

what I am after is the delete function to be within the table - at the moment the delete function is after the newbanktpl, and I want in within... on the last  **ADD DELETED LINK HERE**.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an id to your td, then you can use it in JS.

> In your HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        ...
        <td><a href="#" id="delete">delete</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

> In your `script` tag

```
...
document.getElementById("delete").href="javascript:delIt('+ ct +')";
...
```

> The Entire function should look like this:

```
var ct = 1; 

function new_bank() {
    ct++; 
    var div1 = document.createElement('div');
    div1.id = ct;

    document.getElementById("delete").href="javascript:delIt('+ ct +')"; 
    document.getElementById('newbank').appendChild(div1); 
}
```

P.S. I don't know why you are trying to save bytes from the computer by calling variables with such short names, it's a waist of your time, it won't make any difference to the computer, but it makes it harder to understand your code.

Comment: this doesnt add the the other boxes in the table:   

<td><textarea name="BankAccount[]"></textarea></td>
<td><input type="number" onblur="findTotalA()" name="Value[]"/></td>
<td><input type="number" name="Ownership[]" /></td>

it simply adds a delete text

Comment: I know i have the following in the wrong order could you correct it for me... @rabbishuki

`var ct = 1;
function new_bank()
{
 ct++;
 var div1 = document.createElement('div');
 div1.id = ct;
 // bank to delete extended form elements
 var delLink = '<a href="javascript:delIt('+ ct +')">delete</a>';
 
 div1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('newbanktpl').innerHTML + delLink;
 document.getElementById('newbank').appendChild(div1);
 document.getElementById("delete").href="javascript:delIt('+ ct +')";
}`

Comment: @Cos Seeing as you aren't understanding the solution, I might suggest you get back to the learning seat a bit, and understand how JS works..

Added complete example to help you.

Answer (score 0):

- give the link in the template a class
- clone the template
- update the div's ID
- assign the `delIt` function to the `onclick` of the link
- give the link a `data-delete` attribute that references the ID to delete.
- insert the clone after the last bank that was inserted
- assign the clone as the new "last bank"

```js
var ct = 1;
var tmpl = document.getElementById("newbanktpl");
var lastBank = tmpl;

function new_bank() {
  var clone = tmpl.cloneNode(true);
  clone.id = "bank_" + ct;
  ct++;

  var delLink = clone.querySelector(".delete_link");
  delLink.setAttribute("data-delete", clone.id);
  delLink.onclick = delIt;

  lastBank.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, lastBank.nextSibling);
  lastBank = clone;
}

// function to delete the newly added set of elements
function delIt() {
  var id = this.getAttribute("data-delete");
  var ele = document.getElementById(id);
  if (ele === lastBank) {
    lastBank = ele.previousElementSibling;
  }
  ele.parentNode.removeChild(ele);
  //  findTotalA();
}
```

```css
#newbanktpl {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Template -->
<div id="newbanktpl">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><textarea name="BankAccount[]"></textarea></td>
      <td><input type="number" onblur="findTotalA()" name="Value[]" /></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="Ownership[]" /></td>
      <td><a class="delete_link" href="#">delete</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<button onclick="new_bank()">New Bank</button>
```

Comment: this doesnt seem to be working for me. I have just tried to add it to my code.  what jQuery links do you need for it to work?

Comment: Then you're running the code before the element exists, probably at the top of the page. No jQuery needed.

Comment: Or just move `var tmpl = document.getElementById("newbanktpl");` inside the `new_bank` function at the top.